# Creating a modal window on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, css-frameworks

I am using the Kube framework (http://imperavi.com/kube/) which includes a modal function. Unfortunately the documentation is kind of sparse or I am too dumb (http://imperavi.com/kube/tools/js-modal/).

They have sample code showing how to launch modals on button clicks, but I am trying to launch it on body load. Can anyone with either experience with Kube or a better understanding of JS/JQuery help me do that? I wan to make sure I can specify settings like width and blur.

I know there are many many modal plugins out there, but I am trying to limit my project to just this one framework.

Comment: I think it would be easier to make your own.

Comment: You could always send the developers an email for advice on how to use their plugin.  They have a support page with more contact information.  http://imperavi.com/support/

Answer (score 9):

This will run on window ready. http://jsfiddle.net/418hmnjy/2/. This uses no libraries Just HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<div id="modal">
    <div class="modalconent">
         <h1></h1>

        <p>fasfsdfasfsfsdfsdfsdsffsd</p>
        <button id="button">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('modal').style.display = "none"
    };
};
```

**CSS**

```
#modal {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.modalconent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #fff;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I made a small modification which makes the code perfect